# MacTex Full version

Tags: installing, mactex

I already have downloaded the basic-mactex and have begun using it. But then as I do my research, I begin needing to typeset more complex equations. So I need to download more packages. And I now opted to download the full package.

How can I reinstall my mactex using the full version without affecting the files I created.

Comment: MacTeX only comes in one version, the full one. Do you perhaps mean that you downloaded BasicTeX?

Comment: yes yes. exactly

Comment: @programmer: Download the [Full TeXLive2014 for Mac](https://www.tug.org/mactex/).

Comment: I already have downloaded it. My problem is how to reinstall?

Comment: @programmer: It should be list installing any other s/w on the Mac. Just double click on the downloaded file and follow the instructions.